# Stopping time of $ \min \left\{ n \geq 1 : X_n = Y_n \right\}$

Tags: probability, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1},\mathbb{P})\;$ be a given filtrated probability space, and $X = (X_n)_{n≥1}$ , $Y = (Y_n)_{n≥1}\;$  be two
$(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1}$-martingales. 
Set
$$ \tau := \min \left\{  n \geq 1 : X_n = Y_n \right\} $$
 How we can show that $\tau\;$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1}$-stopping time ?

I need to show that $\left\{\tau \leq n\right\} \in \mathcal{F}_n \; $ for all $n \geq1 $

Comment: What is $\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: @d.k.o. I have modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n \geq1$
$$\{\tau \leq n\}= \bigcup_{k=1}^n{\{Z_k=0\}}$$
where $$Z_k=X_k-Y_k$$

$Z_k$ is $(\mathcal{F}_k)$-measurable, hence your results.

Comment: Can you explain to me why here $Z_k$ is $(\mathcal{F}_k)$-measurable ?

Comment: $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are $\mathcal{F_k}$ measurable by your definition, so is the  difference.